# Does StoreKit support Family Members read and remove programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

Since Apple supports the family subscription function, I have only seen operations for family members in Apple's settings center. I read the official documentation of storekit. Can't seem to find how to modify members via the API

[StoreKit Apple doc link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/supporting_family_sharing_in_your_app)

Solve how to perform member operations through the API code provided by Apple